# Setting the capture size for a video file in OpenCV

Tags: video, opencv, resize, frame

I'm working on a video file to do some processes on its frames. Size of the video is 1280*720 and hereby it is a bit difficult get a good performance(about 1 million pixels for per frame).
So I wanted to reduce its size (640*360 is enough for me) by SetCaptureProperty method of Opencv but it does not work (the Opencv2.2 says it works with only camera captures, not with video files)

I could use resize method of Opencv but I think it is not an efficient way to do it to resize  for every frame.

Can you suggest a better way to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ffpmeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) util to convert the video into a lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the size of frame after the capture the only way I know is the one you are trying to run away from.

Comment: Is there a way before capture? Actually I want to get the video with lower quality( for more performance ). If there is no way, I have to use resize function for every frame. I thought there might be an exact way.

Comment: The only way is to use a tool to manually convert the video and change the dimension of the frames before you open it to process with opencv.

Comment: I can do it but the user may not do it. This is why I am looking for a certain solution by coding before distribution. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: Then you can accomplish this by pre-processing the video with the FFMPEG API.

Comment: Oh, it now sounds useful. I didn't think of using ffmpeg directly in my project. I will try. Thanks :)